# decoding a debian package name (Version,Release)

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging

I would like to know what's the difference between

- `package-name-1.0-0~201~ubuntu14.04.1`
- `package-name-1.0+r201~daily~ubuntu14.04.1`

I am guessing that one of them is a pre-release version but I am not sure.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` character sorts to "less than nothing". I.e. `package-name-1.0-0~201~ubuntu14.04.1` will be upgraded to `package-name-1.0-0~201`; so the '~ubuntu14.04.1` part indicates a prerelease.

When comparing the two versions you show, both are actually prerelease versions.

To find out what version `dpkg` actually considers to be newer:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions '1.0-0~201~ubuntu14.04.1' lt '1.0+r201~daily~ubuntu14.04.1' && echo less than
less than
```

So `1.0-0~201~ubuntu14.04.1` is considered to be less than `1.0+r201~daily~ubuntu14.04.1`.

The rules concerning version numbers is described at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.en.html#namever . This text is for new Debian maintainers, but explains it well for end users as well.